# ASP.NET DropDownList discrepancy between SQL Server ID column and DDL selectedindex

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

Right now I am working on a system that would allow employees to order boots -- and part of the process requires a special user's approval to fully process the order.

The user is meant to select the unfinished order from a dropdownlist, review the order's information, and (with the associated employee's approval), submit the order. What I have noticed is that if you delete an order from the database that loads into the DDL or you edit the order to where it won't have any reason to load into the DDL, the ListItem that loads from the DDL will get confused and say that "There is no row at position 0" (see code below).

The reason for this is in the way the DDL's data is loaded into the DataTable -- which then loads into the ListItem. Because the IDs for the individual loans are being used to load all the loan's information into a DataTable, that ID also holds the responsibility of serving as the loan's index within the DDL. As a result, editing or deleting the loan causes a space in the DDL that the ListItem expects to be occupied by something else. At least as far as I can tell, that is where the error is coming from.

Several elements exist for the panel that this data will load into. In my attempt to circumvent the "there is no row at position 0" error, I tried setting an integer that was also equal to the DDL's SelectedIndex. From there, I tried inserting that integer into the ListItem, but this only resulted in the same kind of error -- where Visual Studio insists there is nothing in that position.

After someone selects something in the order DDL, they are to click a button that will open a popup with all the order's information. Here is what happens after the popup appears:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("loanProc", sc);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

string blNo = ddlBootLoanSel.SelectedIndex.ToString();

DataTable dt = CompC.LoadData("loanProc", sc, new string[] { "id" }, new string[] { blNo });
```

As stated earlier: the ID for the loans is being loaded into the Datatable.
I should also mention CompC here and its method. The way this method works is that it takes in the following parameters:

1. The stored procedure to execute
2. The SQL connection string
3. An array of strings that will be added to the stored procedure; in this case, I need to insert ID if I'm going to update the related table, and
4. The string arguments which, like #3, will be added to the procedure.
   From here, CompC.LoadData will take the procedure results and load them into a table.

```cs
ListItem li = new ListItem(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[0][8].ToString());
ddlFinFullName.Items.Add(li);
lblFinPartNo.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();

// Can't use a Boolean here because this code will need to work with SQL Server
if (dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() == "1") 
    chkFinDiscount.Checked = true;
else
    chkFinDiscount.Checked = false;

lblFinACost.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
lblFinDesc.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
lblFinLastMod.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();

if (dt.Rows[0][6].ToString() == "")
    lblFinAmt.Text = "None";
else
    lblFinAmt.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();

lblFinTP.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();

if (dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() == "1")
    chkFinHF.Checked = true;
else
    chkFinHF.Checked = false;

sc.Close();
lblFinID.Text = blNo;
```

I would expect this to load all the necessary information for the person selected -- but instead (if it doesn't bug out), the popup appears with the person's name wrong UNLESS the person selected is on the index one number below that of the loan that was deleted. For the rest of that session (again: assuming the popup didn't bug out), that one wrong person's name will always appear in the popup box whenever I go to open the popup for any other person.
I also thought there might have been an issue with the ListView not refreshing every time the initiative button was pressed, but I found out there is not any way to clear a ListView with a single command -- and in any event, such a feature would be unnecessary in this case, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is with this line here:

```cs
string blNo = ddlBootLoanSel.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

The SelectedIndex should actually be set as a SelectedValue or SelectedItem.Value. This will take the order's ID and set it in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error and fixed it.

```
int bIndex = ddlBootLoanSel.SelectedIndex;

string blNo= ddlBootLoanSel.Items[bIndex].ToString()
```

or

```
string blNo= ddlBootLoanSel.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Comment: I actually found the problem right here; it all works great now! https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546404/5843693